# problems compiling verovio python toolkit

Tags: python, swig, macos-sierra

I'm trying to compile the verovio python toolkit (verovio.org) with SWIG on a macOS Sierra machine. I run into the following errors that I cannot resolve. Are there any ideas how to get it work?

```
    In file included from ../include/vrv/att.h:16:
    ../include/vrv/vrvdef.h:217:26: error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'std'
    typedef std::vector<std::tuple<Alignment *, Alignment *, int> > ArrayOfAdjustmentTuples;
                        ~~~~~^
    ../include/vrv/vrvdef.h:217:32: error: 'Alignment' does not refer to a value
    typedef std::vector<std::tuple<Alignment *, Alignment *, int> > ArrayOfAdjustmentTuples;
                                   ^
    ../include/vrv/vrvdef.h:195:7: note: declared here
    class Alignment;
          ^
    ../include/vrv/vrvdef.h:217:43: error: expected expression
    typedef std::vector<std::tuple<Alignment *, Alignment *, int> >  ArrayOfAdjustmentTuples;
                                              ^
    ../include/vrv/vrvdef.h:217:63: error: expected unqualified-id
    typedef std::vector<std::tuple<Alignment *, Alignment *, int> > ArrayOfAdjustmentTuples;
                                                                  ^
    In file included from ../src/accid.cpp:17:
    ../include/vrv/functorparams.h:272:5: error: unknown type name 'ArrayOfAdjustmentTuples'
        ArrayOfAdjustmentTuples m_overlapingSyl;
        ^
```

Comment: compiling on a debian dist works fine. But I can't get it done on macOS Sierra

Comment: It turn out that it is a problem with the old version of g++ compiler under xCode 8.

You can find a helpful answer here: https://github.com/rism-ch/verovio/issues/748
Thanks for your help there!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because of a an incompatible installation of python3 an XCode 9. The anaconada installation of python doesn't find any c++11 header files. With the python installation via Homebrew it worked perfectly well.